# How to access to Swashbuckle.AspNetCore protected api to test auto-documentation?

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I'm developing a solution with IdentityServer4, a protected web api and a consumer (console app to testing).

I use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package to auto-document my web api.

In my **ConfigureServices** method in the web api I write this code:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API v1", Version = "v1" });
            c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Info { Title = "API v2", Version = "v2" });
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme()
            {
                AuthorizationUrl = "http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize",
                Flow = "accessCode",
                TokenUrl = "http://localhost:5000/connect/token",
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "api1", "My API" } }
            });
            c.OperationFilter<AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();            
        });
```

When I click to *authorize* button in Swagger.UI page, I redirect to IdentityServer and here I enter user credentials and it works.
So now I have to enter access token (in Swagger.UI page) to access to my protected endpoint to see documentation:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAsync()
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

But **where is the access token saved?**  If I call my api and I put a breakpoint I have the access token in *accessToken* variable.
I think it should do valorized automatically the access token in authorization header? What are the steps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using IdentityServer4 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: @aaronR IdentityServer4 is in .net core 2.0 and my api is in .net core 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using client credentials flow.

Answer (score 0):

try this

> var accesstoken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");